# Using panels and panelizer with i18n

Tags: i18n-l10n, panels

I'm building a multilingual site with 4 different languages, using panels and panelizer, but am struggling to see how to have different panels for different languages.

The site has to be content-manageable by the client, so I need to provide panels that can be translated by them.

I've tried 2 routes - first of all using the i18n_panels submodule in panels. The readme.txt file suggests that I can create a custom pane which can be translated, which would be great, but it isn't very clear how to do this. The example doesn't work.

I've also tried adding a pane for each language and using visibility rules based on the node language. This doesn't work either.

Does anyone have an example of a custom pane that is multilingual using i18n_panels, or another way of achieving the same effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get the i18n_panels module to work, but the Multilingual panels module works a treat.

https://www.drupal.org/project/mlpanels